# JavaScript packages not found/loaded when navigating using vue-router

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, font-awesome

I am building a Vue3 app which uses `vue-router`. I initialized the `<router-view />` component and the necessary `router-links`. When I click on a `<router-link>` element, I am taken to the corresponding page, but the JavaScript modules I used (`apexcharts`, `fontawesome`, ...) are not loading.

An example of this is the `<i>` element, which the `fontawesome` package should render as an icon. Here is a snippet from my source code where I use this:

```html
<i class="ti-trash"></i> Cancel
```

The `<i>` element can be found in the HTML by using the Chrome DevTools, but it is not rendered into an icon, which is what I would have wanted to happen.

Here are relevant snippets of my source code:

`main.js`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Dashboard from '@/components/Dashboard.vue'
import InstanceCreationForm from '@/components/InstanceCreationForm.vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import App from "@/App.vue";

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Dashboard
    },
    {
      path: '/create-instance',
      component: InstanceCreationForm
    }
  ]
})


const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

`Dashboard.vue`:

```
<template>
    <main-template>
        <template v-slot:content>
            <router-link to="/create-instance">
                Add New
            </router-link>
        </template>
    </main-template>
</template>



<script>
import "../js/vendors.min.js" //  <--  Contains jQuery, fontawesome
import "../assets/icons/feather-icons/feather.min.js"
import "../assets/vendor_components/apexcharts-bundle/dist/apexcharts.js"
import "../js/demo.js"
import "../js/jquery.smartmenus.js"
import "../js/menus.js"
import "../js/template.js"
import "../js/pages/dashboard.js"

import MainTemplate from "@/components/MainTemplate.vue";

export default {
    name: "Dashboard",
    extends: MainTemplate,
    components: {MainTemplate}
    metaInfo: {
        script: [
            {src: "https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js", async: true, defer: true},
            {src: "https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js", async: true, defer: true},
            {src: "https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js", async: true, defer: true},
        ]
    }
}
</script>
```

`InstanceCreationForm.vue`:

```
<template>
    <main-template>
        <template v-slot:content>
            <router-link to="/" id="cancel-button" type="button">
              <i class="ti-trash"></i> Cancel
            </router-link>
        </template>
    </main-template>
</template>

<script>
import MainTemplate from "@/components/MainTemplate.vue";

export default {
    name: "InstanceCreationForm",
    components: {MainTemplate},
    extends: MainTemplate,
}
</script>
```

I could solve the problem by using anchor tags (`<a>`) to redirect between routes, but it feels inefficient to reload the entire page every time the user moves pages. The only other solution I could find was either force reloading my component on page load which effectively does the same thing.

Why aren't my JavaScript packages loading on `vue-router` redirect?

Comment: you should read the documentation for libraries like [apexcharts](https://apexcharts.com/docs/vue-charts/) and [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/vue/) which have instructions for how to install them globally.  when you import something in a single component file, it's only available for that component.  some libraries like jquery you should import into single components as needed.

Comment: @yoduh All the plugins are pre-built into the template I'm using for the App. I don't want to go one-by-one redownloading all of them into Vue if they're already available through the template

Comment: The terminology is incorrect. These are libraries, not plugins. It's unclear what "not loading" is supposed to mean. jquery, etc aren't used in the code you posted. The question should have a clear problem statement, otherwise it cannot get a satisfiable answer, with a bounty or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!

The solution was to add the library as a `<src>` tag after the component has mounted:

`MainTemplate.vue`

```
import "../js/vendors.min.js"
import "../assets/icons/feather-icons/feather.min.js"
import "../assets/vendor_components/apexcharts-bundle/dist/apexcharts.js"
import "../js/demo.js"
import "../js/jquery.smartmenus.js"
import "../js/menus.js"
import "../js/template.js"

export default {
name: "MainTemplate",
methods: {
    loadLibrary(libraryPath) {
        let newScript = document.createElement('script')
        newScript.setAttribute('src', libraryPath)
        document.head.appendChild(newScript)
    }
},
mounted() {
    if (this.$options.name === 'MainTemplate') {
        this.loadLibrary("/src/js/vendors.min.js")
        this.loadLibrary("/src/assets/icons/feather-icons/feather.min.js")
        this.loadLibrary("/src/assets/vendor_components/apexcharts-bundle/dist/apexcharts.js")
        this.loadLibrary("/src/js/demo.js")
        this.loadLibrary("/src/js/jquery.smartmenus.js")
        this.loadLibrary("/src/js/menus.js")
        this.loadLibrary("/src/js/template.js")
    }
}
}
```

I chose to put this code in my MainTemplate (because my other components extend from it) rather than use it in each one.

I also kept my original import statements so that they run the first time the site is loaded.